# How to copy a record to another record using the with keyword in C# net5.0

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I am learning C# and trying to write code using records but also implementing dependency inversion.

I have a factory class that I use to create instances of my records called human.

I also use an interface of human which I assume makes my code more loosely coupled and thus implementing dependency inversion (I hope).

I create an instance of human called Paul. When I try to copy Paul using the

> with

keyword so I can change the records name to James, I get an error.

> paul is not null here. The receiver type 'IHuman' is not a valid record type.

What am I doing wrong? Here is my code..

Program.cs

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IHuman paul = Factory.CreateHuman(37, "Male", 5.11, "paul lag");
        IHuman james = paul with { Name="james bond"};
        Console.WriteLine(paul);
        Console.WriteLine(james);
        paul.Living();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Human.cs

```
 public record Human(int Age, string Sex, double Height, String Name) : IHuman
{
    public void Living()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This Human is Living");
    }
}
```

Factory.cs

```
 public static class Factory
{
    public static IHuman CreateHuman(int age,string sex, double height,string name)
    {
        return new Human(age,sex,height,name);
    }
}
```

IHuman.cs

```
public interface IHuman
{
    int Age { get; init; }
    double Height { get; init; }
    string Name { get; init; }
    string Sex { get; init; }

    void Deconstruct(out int Age, out string Sex, out double Height, out string Name);
    bool Equals(Human? other);
    bool Equals(object? obj);
    int GetHashCode();
    void Living();
    string ToString();
}
```

Comment: The problem is that `IHuman` is an interface so the compiler can't be sure it's going to be a record. You could do `(Human)paul with { Name = "james bond" }` or `Human paul = Factory.CreateHuman(37, "Male", 5.11, "paul lag") as Human;` but that is a code smell.

Comment: @Cid, effectively, I removed my off topic comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `IHuman` is an interface so the compiler can't be sure it's going to be a record. Consider the case where another `class` that implements the same interface, that would throw an exception if you tried to use `with`.

You could cast to `Human` either when you do the `with`:

```
IHuman james = (Human)paul with { Name = "james bond" }
```

or when you get the object in the first place:

```
Human paul = Factory.CreateHuman(37, "Male", 5.11, "paul lag") as Human;
```

but they are both a code smell. I really don't see the need for this interface in the first place though. You've essentially copied all of the methods from the `record`. So my advice would be to get rid of it and work directly with the `Human` object.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But wouldn't working directly with `Human` in the main method go against Dependency Inversion as my application is now dependent on full implementations rather than abstract implementations that the interface `IHuman` provides?

Comment: DI is good for things with logic, it's pretty much useless for objects that only contain data.